# How to properly use marshmallow Schema validation in a flask endpoint

Tags: python, flask, pytest, marshmallow

I have a flask api with this endpoint defined

```
@blueprint.route('/people', methods=['POST'])
@use_args(PersonSchema(), locations=('json',))
def create_person(person):
    errors = PersonSchema().validate(person)
    if errors:
        abort(BAD_REQUEST, str(errors))
    person.save()
    return PersonSchema().jsonify(person), HTTPStatus.CREATED
```

and this schema with validators

```
class PersonSchema(BaseModelSchema):
    first_name = fields.Str(required=True)
    last_name = fields.Str()
    email = fields.Email(required=True)
    date_of_birth = fields.Date(required=True)

    @validates('date_of_birth')
    def is_not_in_future(person_schema, date_time):
        now = datetime.now()
        if date_time > now.date():
            raise ValidationError("Cannot be in the future.")

     @validates('email')
     def email_is_not_valid(person_schema, email):
         email_regex_pattern = re.compile("[\w\.]+@+[\w\.]+\.[\w]+")
         if(not email_regex_pattern.match(email)):
             raise ValidationError("Not a valid email address.")

     class Meta:
         model = Person
```

The issue I am seeing is that use of the validator seems to cause a 400 error in this test

```py
def test_can_create_person(db, testapp, person_payload):
    res = testapp.post('/people', json=person_payload)

    assert res.status_code == HTTPStatus.CREATED

    for field in person_payload:
        assert res.json[field] == person_payload[field]
    assert 'id' in res.json

    person = Person.query.get(res.json['id'])

    assert person is not None
    for field in person_payload:
        value = getattr(person, field)
        payload_value = person_payload[field]
        if field in ('date_of_birth',):
            assert str(value) == payload_value
        else:
            assert value == payload_value
```

Can anyone spot what I am doing incorrectly here?

Answer (score 0):

Since you decorate the view with `use_args`, you must be using webargs already. You don't have to validate `person` in the view func. This is already done automagically for you.

And this

```
     class Meta:
         model = Person
```

tells me you're using a lib (flask-marshmallow ?) that instantiates the model for you. It could be the reason `validate` fails. It expects a serialized person, not an object. Although it could work with the object in most cases.

Anyway, make your life simple and appreciate the comfort provided by webargs: don't validate in view functions.